# how to configure spring-boot-starter-security

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-security, spring-boot-starter-security

how I can configure spring-boot-starter-security, to my own needs?

(I'm using spring with kotlin)

I mean, I have this configuration file, but it seems that spring container just ignore.

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean  
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration  
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity  
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity  
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter  
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder  
import java.lang.Exception  
  
@Configuration  
@EnableWebSecurity  
class WebSecurity : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {  
  @Bean  
  public fun encriptator () : BCryptPasswordEncoder{  
  return BCryptPasswordEncoder();  
  }  
  @Throws(Exception::class)  
  override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {  
 http  .authorizeRequests()  
  .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()  
  .anyRequest().authenticated()  
  .and()  
  .formLogin()  
  .loginPage("/login")  
  .permitAll()  
  .and()  
  .logout()  
  .permitAll();  
  }  
}
```

is always redirect me to /login.

And the file location is at the same level of the app.kt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution, my problem was the package keyword was missing, so I move the config file to a package called config, and now its works